# Why is the new movie named Ocean's 8?

Tags: title, oceans-8

What could be the reason to title the movie as *Ocean's 8*, even though Ocean's trilogy (11-12-13) was ended as Ocean's 13?

Comment: Ocean's 8 will give them space for being a new trilogy too.

Comment: [Man Wondering When ‘Ocean's 8’ Trailer Going To Show Film’s Protagonist](https://entertainment.theonion.com/man-wondering-when-oceans-8-trailer-going-to-show-fil-1821508514)

Comment: I guess they couldn't find 14 good actresses in Hollywood :D

Comment: Or maybe they decided that 8 women could easily do the work of 11 men, @JakubTustanowski.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because there are eight con-women in this movie as there were 11, 12 and 13 con-men in the Ocean's trilogy...

Based on Wikipedia:

**Ocean's Eleven:**

1. George Clooney as Danny Ocean
2. Brad Pitt as Rusty Ryan
3. Matt Damon as Linus Caldwell
4. Don Cheadle as Basher Tarr
5. Bernie Mac as Frank Catton
6. Scott Caan as Turk Malloy
7. Casey Affleck as Virgil Malloy
8. Carl Reiner as Saul Bloom
9. Elliott Gould as Reuben Tishkoff
10. Eddie Jemison as Livingston Dell
11. Shaobo Qin as "The Amazing" Yen

**Ocean's Twelve:**

12. Julia Roberts as Tess Ocean

**Ocean's Thirteen:** (Replacing Julia Roberts as the 12th member)

12. Andy García as Terry Benedict
13. Eddie Izzard as Roman Nagel

**Ocean's eight:**

Danny Ocean's estranged sister, **Debbie**, attempts to pull off the heist of the century at New York City's star-studded annual Met Gala. 
 Her first stop is to assemble the perfect crew: 
 **Lou, Rose, Eight Ball, Tammy, Amita, and Constance.**

That's seven members and the 8th member is apparently secret as in usual Ocean's fashion...

Comment: IMO this doesn't answer anything, it only explains that the title is related to the number of protagonists, which is obvious, and the OP already knew that. The questions is: why 8, and not 14?

Comment: Because the story has 8 people instead of 14?

Comment: Well, I took the question too literally! :D

Comment: who knew Julia Roberts is a man?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy - Austin Powers knew, that's who.

Comment: Exactly this. They even give it away in Ocean's Eleven that this is the reason, somewhere during the planning phase if I remember.

Comment: _"secret as in usual Ocean's fashion"_ Who was secret in _Ocean's Eleven_?

Comment: from my understanding it's also a soft reboot

Comment: @Mast: wasn't it in Ocean's 12? When they gather after having been individually threatened by Terry Benedict? One of the thing that annoy some members of the crew the most is to have been labelled "Ocean's 11" by Terry.

Comment: @Taladris Yes, exactly. Now I know why I couldn't find the quote, was searching the wrong script...

Comment: @NikhilEshvar shouldn't the 12th con-men be Gaspar? He's not credited in the movie but IMO he plays pivotal role to lure and con the frenchman (his own apprentice).

Comment: @r41n: Your comment doesn't answer anything either. I mean, why 8 _people_, and not 8 European swallows? Asking the real questions here.

Answer (score 66):

There's no doubt that Nikhil has the right answer for the question as posed, but it might be worth thinking about why they went with 8 and not 14 (as would have been next in the series), or 10 (just before 11) or any other number.

I personally think they were reaching the limit for how many main characters they could have. When they wanted an all female cast, they needed an all new cast (it would probably have been confusing to put Julia Roberts in) and that means they need time to tell some backstories, but they also want time to tell a story. It's a lot easier to squeeze in 8 than 14. Also it's easier for the audience to separate 8 characters and remember what each one's skills are (I know that I struggled the first time I watched Ocean's 11).

By going back to 8 instead of just 10, they still have enough that's it's a large enough gang to pull off a spectular heist and they leave room for some (2, i.e. a new trilogy) successors with consecutive numbers. - If the movie doesn't flop big time, my money is on us getting "Ocean's 9" within a couple of years.

Comment: i like your answer ! both this and the accepted ! makes a lot of sense .. 14, 15, 16 would be super complex and chaotic.

Comment: This. Think about The Hobbit: Bilbo and a party of 13 dwarves.  Even with three extended length movies, most viewers probably don't even know the *names* of all 13 dwarves, much less their backstories, skills, and individuality.  Imagine trying to introduce 14 new characters *and* tell a good story in a single feature length film.  Most people can't connect with that level of ADHD.  Too much chaos and disconnect.

Comment: Furthermore, when starting at eight, the final part of a possible trilogy has the number ten, therefore not coinciding with the first part of the previous trilogy, Ocean's Eleven.

Comment: Yeah, 11 characters in Ocean's 11 was stretching it imo

Comment: I'm confused--are you saying female characters need more backstory than male characters? Or just that starting with a new cast meant they needed enough backstory that going to 14 would be too much, or what?

Comment: @MissMonicaE: I only meant to say that an all new cast requires more backstories than some recurring characters. I hope the edit makes that clearer.

Comment: I wouldn't take that bet. I am however interested in what they are going to do 3 sequels from now. (Besides drown in all that cash of course). Oceans 11-2, perhaps?

Comment: This is probably not right. It's certainly not expense -- since women earn 70% as much as men, they could have afforded 18 with the same budget.

Comment: Ocean's 11 was helped in this regard by Turk and Virgil Malloy being brothers and in effect only needing one to share one personality and identity.

Answer (score 7):

Ahem... **[8th March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Women%27s_Day)** is International Woman's Day. It can't be merely a coincidence.

> International Women's Day (IWD) is celebrated on March 8 every year. It commemorates the movement for women's rights.
>
> [...] **March 8** was suggested by the 1910 International Woman's Conference to become an "International Woman's Day." [..] it was adopted in 1975 by the United Nations.

By Henrik's logic, **Ocean's 7** would have worked equally as well, there's one less name to remember, and the number seven recurs in [**several movies**](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls006357830/) but the producers (I assume) chose 8. They could have gone for 6 but that number is not generally considered lucky in the Occident whereas the number 8, in China, is considered auspicious.

> **No. 8** has long been regarded as the luckiest number in Chinese culture. With pronunciation of 'Ba' in Chinese, **no. 8 sounds similar to the word 发 'Fa', which means to make a fortune**

from the same website

> The popularity of 8 was obvious in relation to the Beijing Olympic Games which commenced at exactly [eight o’clock eight minutes on the eighth day of the eighth month in 2008](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/intro/lucky-number8.htm). When people choose telephone numbers, mobile numbers, house numbers, car identification numbers and important dates, 8 is usually the first choice.

Another coincidence? Could be.

Comment: Then why not _Ocean's 38_?

Comment: @Chloe maybe because.... **3+8 =11** OMG it's.... Ocean's 11... :)

Comment: @Chloe perhaps  because in much of the world it would be Ocean's 83.

Comment: Why can't it be merely a coincidence? It looks coincidental to me.

Comment: @Leviathan the release date for the movie is [**8 June, 2018**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5164214/), nuff said. Maybe March is not a great month for big movies, so the producers opted for June.

Comment: Right, June - not March.

Comment: Chinese market.... movies need every gimmick they can grab their greedy little hands on `No. 8 has long been regarded as the luckiest number in Chinese culture. With pronunciation of 'Ba' in Chinese, no. 8 sounds similar to the word 'Fa', which means to make a fortune.`

Comment: That's really far fetched...

Comment: @ShadowWizard everything above is

Comment: @Vishwa not really. The accepted answer appears to be very solid and very much correct, not a wild guess.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no I mean about this answer